# Can I embed another running exe inside my visual basic form?

Tags: vb.net

I started experimenting with embeding another .exe in my form. I managed to run another program and use it inside a forms panel. Is there a way to put inside this panel an already running exe?

```
Public Class Form1
Declare Auto Function SetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As Integer
Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
 Dim proc As Process

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    proc = Process.Start("C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe")
    proc.WaitForInputIdle()
    SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, Panel1.Handle)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Have you tried `Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")` instead of Process.Start?

Comment: How would I change that, I get this error if I change it.

Value of type 'Process()' cannot be converted to 'Process'. @AlexB.

Comment: `dim proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault() if proc isnot nothing then ...`. You also need `MoveWindow` or `SetWindowPos` or similar. Expect some irritated responses. Btw, you should declare the function with a `<DllImport())>` Attribute, not with the `Declare Auto` version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code becomes like this. The notepad.exe needs to be running , on startup it embeds the notepad.exe on the main form. Thanks a lot.

```
Public Class Form1
Declare Auto Function SetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As Integer
Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault()
    If proc IsNot Nothing Then
        SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, Panel1.Handle)
    End If
        End Sub
End Class
```